# JavaScript Prototypes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why in MDN functions polyfills use  "if (!Array.prototype.filter)" ?

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
    'use strict';

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;    
    var res = [];
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t) {
        var val = t[i];

        if (fun.call(thisArg, val, i, t)) {
          res.push(val);
        }
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

What do you need to use it?

Comment: If the `filter` prototype of `Array` type doesn't exists.. the script create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how they check to see if the thing they're polyfilling is already present.

To use that specific example: `Array.prototype` refers to the object that is the prototype of all arrays. So `Array.prototype.filter` is the property that arrays inherit that provides the `filter` method. By doing `if (!Array.prototype.filter)`, the code checks to see if that property already exists with a truthy value (a function reference is truthy) and doesn't try to add it if it's present. Reading the value of `Array.prototype.filter` will yield `undefined` (a falsy value) if `filter` isn't present on `Array.prototype`, which tells the code it needs to add the polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

> What do you need to use it?

if the native method does exist the polyfill doesn't overwrite it